# Tailwind Not Generating all col-span-{n} classes correctly

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following in my Tailwind config file:

```
{
    ...
    gridColumn: {
      auto: 'auto',
      'span-1': 'span 1 / span 1',
      'span-2': 'span 2 / span 2',
      'span-3': 'span 3 / span 3',
      'span-4': 'span 4 / span 4',
      'span-5': 'span 5 / span 5',
      'span-6': 'span 6 / span 6',
      'span-7': 'span 7 / span 7',
      'span-8': 'span 8 / span 8',
      'span-9': 'span 9 / span 9',
      'span-10': 'span 10 / span 10',
      'span-11': 'span 11 / span 11',
      'span-12': 'span 12 / span 12',
      'span-full': '1 / -1',
    }
}
```

but when I generate my Tailwind CSS, I'm missing one generating `.col-span-{n}` class and I can't figure out why. If I comment out `span-3` (or any `span-{n}`)from the config above the missing class is generated but obviously, I'm missing the class I commented out.

Comment: It seems to work ok, https://play.tailwindcss.com/NVzXJYx6Fn, is there something else in your config affecting this?

Comment: It's happening to me too, but it's intermittent.  I suspect it's a bug with svelte / vite / tailwind transpiling.  I noticed the `.col-span-3` CSS class was missing from the div in the "styles" tab (using chromium)